# Is it possible to Customize the Text input Scope of Textbox?

Tags: windows-phone-7

in my application I used a Textbox with input scope "text". When I type in Textbox, I can see a suggestion bar above the keyboard which contains some words.If I type a in Textbox I can see the words "and","are","at"...etc.I want to customize these words.
for example if I type "a" I want to show the names "alan","alex"..etc.
Is there any way to change this?
Please help me

Is there anyway to customize the words appearing in the auto complete suggestion bar for text input scope in

Comment: What technology are you creating this in for windows phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also can't do anything AT ALL with the keyboard.  If this is for a custom app, perhaps a list would work such as the list in the people hub for example.  Pretty sure MS isn't releasing any keyboard API's for WP8 either, so the only alternative is a workaround or alternate method.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to control text suggestions in the auto-complete bar. You are only able to choose type of input scope and no more.